# Laravel model: update only one field

Tags: php, laravel

I have validation rules for my model:

```
protected $fillable = array('username','firstname','lastname',"street","city","country","birthday","email");

public static $rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|between:4,16|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:4',
    'firstname' => 'required|alpha_num|between:2,16',
    'lastname' => 'required|alpha_num|between:2,32',
);
```

and my update method:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);        
    $data = Input::all();       
    if ( isset($data['firstname']) ) {
        $user->firstname = $data['firstname'];
    }

    $success = $user->update();

    if ( $success ) {
        return Response::json(array('error' => false, 'user' => $user->toArray()), 200 );
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('error' => true, 'message' => $user->errors()->all()), 400 );   
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting an error:

```
 {
    "error": true,
    "message": [
        "The username has already been taken.",
        "The email has already been taken."
    ]
}
```

So, the question is: How can I update only one field of the model?

**UPDATE:**

As I'm using Ardent (https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) I could do:

```
$success = $user->updateUniques();
```

and everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that when updating the model, validation *unique* requirements detects that username and email already exists. To avoid that, append the currently updating id instance to the make the validator. In the validator use a parameter to detect if you are updating or creating it, and send the user id in the first case, then you can use:

Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID

```
'username' => 'required|between:4,16|unique:users,'.$userId,
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,'.$userId,
```

More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22406205/1165509

Comment: How do I append the currently updating id instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function setConditionalRules($model)
{
    $id = $model->getKey();
    foreach(['email', 'username'] as $field)
    {
        $this->validator->sometimes($field, $this->rules[$field].",$id", function($input) use($model, $field)
        {
            if($model->exists)
            {
                $this->validator->setRules(array_except($this->validator->getRules(), [$field]));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

}
```