# Laravel 4 Unique Validation Rules Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-validation

need help updating a unique rule in my validation rules. I have a abstract validator that will validate a rules before storing into my database and in the rules array I set the email to be unique when creating or registering a user but when updating the user the enique email should not validate if the email is owned by the user.

**abstract class Validator**

```
abstract class Validator {

    protected $errors;

    protected $attributes;

    public function __construct($attributes = null)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes ?: \Input::all();
    }

    public function passes()
    {
        $validation = \Validator::make($this->attributes, $this->rules());

        if ($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

**Validation Rules(UserRule.php)**

```
use MyCustomValidatorNamespaceHere....

class UserRules extends Validator

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,id',
        ...
    ];
}
```

and in my UserController I injected the UserRule in the constractor. (UserRule $userRule). Here is the code in the update method.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $if ($this->userRule->passes())
    {
       $this->user->find($id)->update(Input::all());
       return .........
    }
}
```

But the validation always fail and displaying the error that the email is already taken. Please help guys.

Comment: I solved this problem [here on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28254548/1532168) in a generic way. It will automatically adapt your rules if you do an update and add exceptions to your `:unique` if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your rule. When you update, you need to use `unique` that doesn't check record you update. So you should have:

```
 unique:users,email,id
```

but for example:

```
 unique:users,email,10
```

if you edit record with id 10.

What you could do is to define this rule:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,{id}',
```

and your `passes` method:

```
public function passes($id = null)
{
    $rules = $this->rules();
    $rules['email'] = str_replace('{id}', $id, $rules['email']);

    $validation = \Validator::make($this->attributes, $rules);

    if ($validation->passes()) return true;

    $this->errors = $validation->messages();

    return false;
}
```

and now in update rule use:

```
if ($this->userRule->passes($id))
```

By the way you have error in `$if ($this->userRule->passes())` - it should be `if` and not `$if`

Comment: How about if I have more unique that should be excluded when updating. I think I should add it again in the passes method?

Comment: @piso For unique you can only use one id not many. You should edit only one record at once so it's enough.

Comment: How about when updating the username? username is also unique btw.

Comment: @piso you can pass to passes array of arguments and make more changes to your existing rules. You can modify username rule as I showed you with email and do the same for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `route` method inside your request class to except an id from the validation

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('user'),
        ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that before and it was difficult to find an answer.  Here is what I did.

```
class UserRules extends Validator {

public function __construct($input = NULL) {
    $this->input = $input ?: \Input::all();
    if(isset($this->input['id'])):
        self::$rules['username'] = 'required|unique:users,username,'.$this->input['id'];
        self::$rules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->input['id'];
    else:
        self::$rules['username'] = 'required|unique:users';
        self::$rules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:users';
    endif;
}

public static $rules = array(
    'company_id' => 'required',
    'role' => 'required',
    'password' => 'sometimes|required|confirmed'
);

}
```

You need to use `self::` because $rules is static.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved this function:

```
public function passes($id)
{

    $rules = static::$rules;

    $rules['username'] = str_replace('{id}', $id, $rules['username']);
    $rules['email'] = str_replace('{id}', $id, $rules['email']);

    $validation = \Validator::make($this->attributes, $rules);

    if($validation->passes()) return true;

    $this->errors = $validation->messages();

    return false;

}
```

into UserRule.php and commented the same function in abstract class Validator
Now updating is working.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28254548/1532168) in a generic way. It will automatically adapt your rules if you do an update and add exceptions to your `:unique` if necessary.