# Ignore unique rule for a id laravel not working

Tags: validation, laravel-5, unique, rules

Following [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405762/laravel-update-model-with-unique-validation-rule-for-attribute) tutorial, I have modified my rules to

```
$id = Crypt::decrypt($id); 
$rules = Department::$rules;

$rules['name']              = $rules['name'] . ',id,' . $id;
$rules['department_code']   = $rules['department_code'] . ',id,' . $id;
//dd($rules);
$validator = Validator::make($data = $request->all(), $rules); dd($rules);
if ($validator->fails()) return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

in my `update()` function. But it is showing data already exists ! How to ignore the rules for this `ID` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example which is ignoring the `unique` rules for the specific ID

```
'username'          => 'required|unique:users,username,'.$user->id,
```