# Laravel 5.6. The unique validation rule. Exclude from the scan the field of the current record, if it did not change

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I have a validation class:

```
    class AnalyseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        'code' => 'required|code_format|unique:analyses',
    }
}
```

The code field stores the code, which must be unique. There is a template where this code is displayed for editing. I edit other fields, I do not touch the code. I keep my form. Then this rule is triggered. Tell me please, how can I set up the validator so that it works correctly when this value is edited to a new one?

Comment: This issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405762/laravel-update-model-with-unique-validation-rule-for-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
'code' => 'required|code_format|unique:analyses,code,'.$this->id,
```