# Concaternate Array value with Ternary Operator result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, ternary

I'm using PHP 7 and Laravel 6. I got errors when I made a user request rule and used it in user controller. The request rule I made is to be reusable in create and update function, so if i pass the id of user, it will validate the unique of user except that id. But if not, it will search all the ids and validate if it's unique. I follow BaM solution, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205849

This my UserRequest.php:

```
public static function rules ($id=0, $merge=[]) {
    return array_merge(
        [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users' . ($id ? ",$id" : ''),
            'phone_number' => 'required|string|min:9|max:10|unique:users' . ($id ? ",$id" : ''),
            'user_img' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:10000',
        ], 
            $merge);
}
```

This is my UserController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $extend_rules = [
      'pass'       => 'required|string|min:8',
  ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), UserRequest::rules($extend_rules));

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
      return redirect()->back();
    }

    $user = User::create([
      'name' => $request->name,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => Hash::make($request->pass),
      'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
      'user_img' => $request->user_image->store('user_img'),
    ]);

    $user->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Your account is successfully created !');
    Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert alert-success');
    

    return redirect()->route('users.index');
    
  }
```

And I got this errors:

ErrorException: Array to string conversion

I tried to search for solutions but couldn't seem to find anything much my case.

If anyone know, please help me!

Comment: Well, `UserRequest::rules` is expecting an integer ID and an array as its parameters. I'm guessing you need to pass `0` as first param for new users, but I'm unfamiliar with Laravel so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Jeto But i already have $id=0 as default in the rule function. The problem is i can't concatenate the array value with ternary operation. It gave me an error: "Array to string conversion".

Comment: It doesn't matter that you have `$id=0`. The first parameter that function expects is still that, `$id`. Not to sound rude, but this is very basic stuff. You should read the [manual page on function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're just passing an array while the method accept two different type of parameter

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), UserRequest::rules(0, $extend_rules)); // <-- you need to either pass 1 or 0 for the id and then $extended rules

// here is your method signature
public static function rules ($id=0, $merge=[]) {
```

Comment: @SovanSamboNgeth It would be nice to accept the answer as question remain open will waste others time to look into it. Just click on the middle of "0" if you are new to `SO`. Thanks