# Form validator unique username fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm having difficulties detecting a unique username. I mean it does work to detect username but I would like to exclude the username validation if the request input username matches with that users current username in database.

Currently, I'm getting: *The username has already been taken.* despite the fact the its the same username as the one this user has in the database.

Thank you!

Rules

```
    protected $rules = [
        'username'  => 
 'nullable|string|alpha_dash|max:255|regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u|unique:users',
        'first_name' => 'nullable|max:150',
     'last_name' => 'nullable|max:150', 
      'location' => 'nullable|max:200', 
      'password' => 'confirmed'
    ];
```

Edit Profile POST method:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return \redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray())->withInput($request->except('image'));
        } else {
            $model = \App\User::find(\Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405762/laravel-update-model-with-unique-validation-rule-for-attribute/22406205

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel update model with unique validation rule for attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405762/laravel-update-model-with-unique-validation-rule-for-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On update you can ignore the field as :

```
'username'  => 
 'nullable|string|alpha_dash|max:255|regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u|unique:users,' . $user->id,
```

Or,

```
'username' => [
   'nullable',
   'string',
   Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
```

You may pass a different column name as the second argument to the unique method:

```
Rule::unique('users', 'username')->ignore($user->id),
```

You may also specify additional query constraints by customizing the query using the where method. For example :

```
Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('username', '!=',  $request->username);
})
```

Comment: @Nish this is an another error, you can solve it by https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations-error